# Why are "yay" updates sourcing .bashrc?

Tags: bash, upgrade, pacman

I have a line in my `.bashrc` file that prints the current time and system uptime, so that that always appears at the top when I open a console. However, this also occurs at random time whenever I update my system with `yay` and I'm pretty sure it also happens during new installations.

Example:

```
(493/713) upgrading linux510                                                                                                                   [#######################################################################################] 100%
(494/713) upgrading linux510-acpi_call                                                                                                         [#######################################################################################] 100%
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
up 7 hours since 2021-12-10 18:08:04, time: 01:08:06
  > Updating module dependencies...
(495/713) upgrading linux510-bbswitch                                                                                                          [#######################################################################################] 100%
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
up 7 hours since 2021-12-10 18:08:04, time: 01:08:16
(496/713) upgrading linux510-broadcom-wl                                                                                                       [#######################################################################################] 100%
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
up 7 hours since 2021-12-10 18:08:04, time: 01:08:28
(497/713) upgrading linux510-headers                                                                                                           [#######################################################################################] 100%
(498/713) upgrading linux510-nvidia                                                                                                            [#######################################################################################] 100%
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
up 7 hours since 2021-12-10 18:08:04, time: 01:08:57
(499/713) upgrading linux510-r8168                                                                                                             [#######################################################################################] 100%
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
up 7 hours, 1 minute since 2021-12-10 18:08:04, time: 01:09:09
(500/713) upgrading linux510-rtl8723bu                                                                                                         [#######################################################################################] 100%
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
up 7 hours, 1 minute since 2021-12-10 18:08:04, time: 01:09:25
(501/713) upgrading linux510-tp_smapi                                                                                                          [#######################################################################################] 100%
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
up 7 hours, 1 minute since 2021-12-10 18:08:04, time: 01:09:46
(502/713) upgrading linux510-vhba-module                                                                                                       [#######################################################################################] 100%
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
up 7 hours, 1 minute since 2021-12-10 18:08:04, time: 01:09:58
  > Updating module dependencies...
(503/713) upgrading linux510-virtualbox-host-modules                                                                                           [#######################################################################################] 100%
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
up 7 hours, 2 minutes since 2021-12-10 18:08:04, time: 01:10:13
In order to use the new version, reload all virtualbox modules manually.
(504/713) upgrading stk                                                                                                                        [#######################################################################################] 100%
New optional dependencies for stk
    stk-docs: for documentation
    tk: for demos and samples [installed]
(505/713) upgrading lmms                                                                                                                       [#######################################################################################] 100%
(506/713) upgrading lollypop                                                                                                                   [#######################################################################################] 100%
(507/713) upgrading lsp-plugins                                                                                                                [#######################################################################################] 100%
New optional dependencies for lsp-plugins
    lsp-plugins-docs: for documentation
(508/713) upgrading m17n-lib                                                                                                                   [#######################################################################################] 100%
(509/713) upgrading slop                                                                                                                       [#######################################################################################] 100%
(510/713) upgrading maim                                                                                                                       [#######################################################################################] 100%
(511/713) installing sddm-breath-theme                                                                                                         [#######################################################################################] 100%
(512/713) upgrading xdg-desktop-portal-kde                                                                                                     [#######################################################################################] 100%
(513/713) upgrading manjaro-kde-settings                                                                                                       [#######################################################################################] 100%
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
up 7 hours, 2 minutes since 2021-12-10 18:08:04, time: 01:10:25
cp: cannot create regular file '/var/lib/sddm/.config/kdeglobals': No such file or directory
error: command failed to execute correctly
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
up 7 hours, 2 minutes since 2021-12-10 18:08:04, time: 01:10:25
(514/713) upgrading manjaro-release                                                                                                            [#######################################################################################] 100%
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
up 7 hours, 2 minutes since 2021-12-10 18:08:04, time: 01:10:25
(515/713) upgrading manjaro-settings-manager                                                                                                   [#######################################################################################] 100%
(516/713) upgrading manjaro-settings-manager-kcm                                                                                               [#######################################################################################] 100%
(517/713) upgrading manjaro-settings-manager-knotifier                                                                                         [#######################################################################################] 100%
(518/713) upgrading matcha-gtk-theme                                                                                                           [#######################################################################################] 100%
stty: 'standard input': Inappropriate ioctl for device
up 7 hours, 2 minutes since 2021-12-10 18:08:04, time: 01:10:27
```

Those `stty` errors come from the line `stty intr ^-`, which, according to the internet, happens because the `stty` command doesn't expect to be run in such a context. But that's OK, because **I** also didn't expect it to run in such a context.

So far I have not seen any issues with sourcing my `.bashrc` during updates, but since I overwrite some commands (like `echo` with `echo -e`), it could in theory happen.

Long ago, I did remove the line from `.bashrc` that stops its execution in non-interactive situations, because I want to be able to use it from within scripts, too. Of course I could put that line back in to stop this from happening, but I'm more wondering:
Why are updates doing this at all? And is there a way to stop that specifically only for updates (with `yay`/`pacman`)?

Comment: Better option is to move things you want even if not interactive to above the line, and put interactive-only things below the line.

Comment: @Ben Good idea, I'll probably do that if I ever see an actual issue with this.